# Videojs translation for play button *title*

Tags: video.js

I am trying to use the language option on Videojs to have the play button's title text to be translated but that is not working... I am not sure what am I doing wrong..

I'm not sure if I am missing an import, but since I am using the npm package I thought that the imports were being done by videojs package...

https://codesandbox.io/s/videojs-forked-xt74qq

[image]

Comment: Instead of `lang: "fr-ca",` try using `language: "fr-ca",` -- see: https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-languages.html#setting-default-player-language

Comment: tried that, didn't work :( https://codesandbox.io/s/videojs-forked-xt74qq?file=/src/index.js

Comment: You need to import the language translations similar to here https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-butterfly-80pibt?file=/src/video.js However trying that with your project, codesandbox is unable to find node_modules for some reason.

Comment: @misterben it is so weird, because we cannot see the files on codesandbox, but on my local application there are no lang folder inside of the videojs node_modules, so basically this "video.js/dist/lang/de.json" doesn't work... any idea how to add the folders in there? Is it a separate dependency? From the example you sent it doesn't seem like it and I even using the exact same videojs version as the example you sent...

Comment: Actually your codesandbox has an old version of Video.js, 6.8.0, and that's the problem. The lang json files are only in the dist folder since 7.4.0 https://github.com/videojs/video.js/releases/tag/v7.4.0

Comment: Sorry, my local version is 7.17.0.... sandbox is now updated, and it works hahaha but my local doesn't :(

Comment: Also, will I always need to import all languages even though I might not need them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer for this was a mix of both @misterben and @blurfus answers, I had to:

1. Switch `lang: "fr-ca"` for `language: "fr-ca"` inside the options;
2. Add an import for the language I needed, like: `import fr from 'video.js/dist/lang/fr.json';`
3. Add the language in the videojs object `videojs.addLanguage('fr', fr);`